# Is there `Rails.on_load` event or like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to access `Rails.logger` to tune it’s formatter. While `Rails` executes `config/application.rb`, `Rails.logger` is not defined yet. Neither it is defined in `config/environments/*.rb`.

So, my question: is there any place I can safely put my initialization, relying on that `Rails.logger` is already set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a callback:

```
config.after_initialize do |app|
  # put everything here
end
```